# Updating selected rows JDBC RowSet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, rowset

I want to update a record in a database using JDBC RowSet. I first get the required record and then I use updateRow() to update. But it doesn't get reflected on the database. There are no errors reported.

```
rowSet.setCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE uid="+e.getUid());
rowSet.execute();
rowSet.updateString("name", e.getName());
// More update operations
rowSet.updateRow();
```

Comment: Do you have `autoCommit()==true` / have you called `rowSet.commit()` explicitly?

Comment: I believe autoCommit = true because insertion and deletion is working fine without rowSet.commit()

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcrowset.html#updating-column-value) example show that you must first move to the changed line using

```
 jdbcRs.absolute(3);
```

to update the third row.

Note also that in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jcrowset.htm) the rowset must be made explicitly updatable

```
 rowset.setReadOnly (false);
```

Comment: Where does "3" come from?

Comment: This navigates to the third row, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcrowset.html#navigating-jdbcrowset-object)